# component parameter is undefined on useDrop:hover(props,monitor,components) hook

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am trying to do some calculations for position inside useDrop:hover() .But not able to proceed because component prop is undefined on hover.Following is my implementation for useDrop Hook:

```
const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: getAcceptType(schema),
    drop: addComponentOnDrop(schema),
    collect: monitor => ({
      isOver: monitor.isOver({ shallow: true }),
      canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
    }),
    hover(props, monitor,component) {
      console.log(component);
      debugger
      if (!monitor.canDrop()) {
        return;
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: hover will return only   hover(item, monitor) { // refer https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop

Comment: @PrakashKarena You are right to some extent . But I have seen on several places where people doing calculation of position Inside hover.Please follow the following link :https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/1493#issuecomment-519148450
Correct me if i am wrong or there is some issue with this approach.

Comment: what you exactly want to do with use drop hover ??

Comment: Inside useDrop:hover() method i want to check position of hovered element wether it is above or below the drop target.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_hooks_js/04-sortable/simple?from-embed you can refer this example which helps you how you can achieve your goal